# TinyMCE 4: How to make toolbar use full width of its fixed_toolbar_container

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I initialize my tinyMCE Editor like this:

```
this.editor = tinymce.init({
    ...
    target: anElementRef,
    inline: true,
    theme: 'modern',
    menubar: false,
    statusbar: false,
    fixed_toolbar_container: anotherElementRef,
    ...
 });
```

The toolbar renders at the correct place, but I want it to take full width of its container element like:
[image]

Any ideas how to achieve that? Thanks!

Comment: Which of the fixed width controls in the toolbar would you expect to automatically expand so that the space can be filled and how would you expect that it would do this?

Comment: Just blank space in background color would be great.